# DPI Scaling Level affecting win32gui GetWindowRect in Python

Tags: python, windows-10, win32gui

When GetWindowRect() is called in Python, the values it returns are inaccurate if a DPI scaling level of anything but 100% is used. Is there any way to get around this, or mathematically adjust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make your program DPI aware using windll from ctypes:

```
from ctypes import windll

# Make program aware of DPI scaling
user32 = windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```

From that point on calls like GetWindowRect() should return the proper values.  I stumbled upon this solution a while back trying to get Pyautogui to give me proper screenshots.